# access custom folder files in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

after uploading files in a custom folder "myuploads", I want to access these files in the admin page. 
This folder resides in the root directory along with wp-admin,wp-content,wp-includes folder. I have also tried links like "/myuploads/filename"  or "../myuploads/filename" in admin but both give

> "oops! that page cannot be accessed error".

I am new to wordpress so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by you want to “access” them _in_ the admin page?

Comment: User uploads a file from a contact page which gets saved in myuploads folder for e.g. he uploads mycontract.docx.  now in admin i am adding a link like  <a href="/myuploads/mycontract.docx">user file</a> but when i click on this link it says page not found.

Comment: How does the upload happen, is that a plugin taking care of that, or something else, self-written perhaps? Why is this uploading to a folder in that location, why does it not follow the usual WP way of placing such stuff underneath /wp-content/uploads/…?

Comment: I needed a custom form with multiple fields including file uploads. so I used PHP file upload function `move_uploaded_file()` to upload the files to a folder "myuploads". 
Now in the admin I am trying to add a link in the LIST page where by clicking on this link admin can download these files. 
Do you mean in my PHP code I should upload the files in wp-content/uploads folder ? then the link in admin work ? I am not using any plugin

Comment: We don’t know why it is “not working” now, so there is no guarantee it will work then. You need to properly analyse _why_ it is not working. First of all, have you checked the files were actually uploaded successfully? You can see them via FTP? What do the file system permissions look like, do those match other files from the wp-contents uploads folder that you _can_ access?